# sql server delete duplicate records from a table after checking if these records are there in dependent table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables as below

Table_1
APP_MED_CHIP_ID   APPLICATION_ID       PERSON_ID 
248340                                  1228144                           1028940 
248342                                  1228144                           1028940

328526                            1273218                           818905
328527                            1273218                           1386405
328528                            1273218                           1386407

Table_2
APP_MED_CHIP_DETAIL_ID       APP_MED_CHIP_ID
92574                                                                                    248342

In table 1 first 2 records are duplicates as they have the same application_id and person_id, so I need to take APP_MED_CHIP_ID (248340,248342) of these 2 records, check if these are present in table 2, then delete the record from table 1 that is not present in table 2.

I have used the below query to select all the duplicates.

```
SELECT * FROM <br>
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY APPLICATION_ID,PERSON_ID ORDER BY APPLICATION_ID,PERSON_ID) as ROW,* 
FROM Table_1) as p<br>
where p.APP_MED_CHIP_ID not in<br> 
(select APP_MED_CHIP_ID from Table_2)<br>
and p.ROW > 1
```

Problem with my query is with the first set of records in Table_1, my result set will not show first set of records as I used the condition p.ROW > 1, but if I do not use this condition I will not be able to filter the duplicates.

I have shown just 2 sets of records as example, but there are many other records in my table_1 as the this.

Please advise on how to solve this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> delete the record from table 1 that is not present in table 2

So, I think you want to delete "duplicate" rows in Table_1 that do not exist in Table_2. You only want to delete rows when there is more than record when grouped by APPLICATION_ID and PERSON_ID.

You could probably do something like this:

```
Delete From Table_1
Where APP_MED_CHIP_ID Not In
(
    Select APP_MED_CHIP_ID From Table_2
)
And Exists
(
    Select 1 From Table_1 As T1
    Where Table_1.APPLICATION_ID = T1.APPLICATION_ID
       And Table_1.PERSON_ID = T1.PERSON_ID
    Having Count(*) > 1
)
```

Of course, the root issue is that dirty data is allowed in Table_1. If you have any control over the DDL, you could put a constraint on `Table_1`, such as a FK where `Table_1.APP_MED_CHIP_ID` references `Table_2.APP_MED_CHIP_ID` or a unique constraint on `Table_1` columns (`APPLICATION_ID`, `PERSON_ID`). If you do not have any control over the DDL, I feel for you.

Comment: Hi Mike,thanks for your response. I have a problem with above query, second set of records in my table_1 (i.e. APP_MED_CHIP_ID = 328526,328527,328528) none of these are present in table_2, your query will select all these 3 records, but I need to delete only 2 records & keep 1 record out of these three. Please advise on how to achieve this?

Comment: I am not 100% certain I understand your end goal, but maybe add to the Where clause something like `And PERSON_ID In (Select PERSON_ID From Table_1 Group By PERSON_ID Having Count(*) > 1)`

Comment: Hi Mike, my problem is solved. I used your query to select all the duplicates, used Row_Number() in my select, deleted all the rows having Row_Number = 1, re ran the same query for 4 times until all the duplicates are deleted.